# What is good software to build textures in

Tags: textures, 2d-games

i am looking to build some textures for a 2Dgame i am developing but i don't know what would be good software for the job, does anyone have some suggestions on what i could use?

thanks
Steve

Answer (score 0):

i think solid works is what you are loking for, solid can draw in 3d
gimp for shure, xfig is more for structures projects.

Try solid works i think is the best software do 2d draw

Comment: i looked into Solid work and at the moment it is a bit pricey for me, i am looking at some free CAD called archimedes.